# send parameter with jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is my sample code populating data table on my app.But i want to send a parameter with the url !!

Parameter name '**form**' integer value.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "getKeyDetails.html",

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: have you tried changing the URL like `"url": "getKeyDetails.html?form=1"`

Comment: yup i getting response from server. but the parameter is dynamic

Comment: from where this dynamic integer value will come? I hope the parameter name **form** is still the static one and will not change.

Comment: i mean parameter value not the name.

Comment: ya..its ok but from where this parameter value needs to be picked? Is it coming from a select box, text box or any other JavaScript variable?

Comment: it's coming from select box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering above inputs from your end you can check below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var paramValue = $("#yourSelectBoxID").val();

        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "getKeyDetails.html?form="+paramValue,

            }
        });
});
```

Here we are assuming that there is a `select` box on your page with an `id` `yourSelectBoxID`. So whatever value is selected on DOM ready; that value will be passed within URL to the server side.